# Why does my horizontal form in bootstrap need to be in full window width to respond

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to ake a contact form very simple with bootstrap and I would like to have email and name beside eachother using col-md-6. I want it show email and name displayed beside eachother when viewed on desctop. Everything is working fine except that when the two form groups, Name and Email are beside eachother it is not possible to fill them in, like if they where deactivated.

Here is the very simple code I am using `               
                    
                            
                               
                                    
                                    Name:

```
                             <div class="form-group" class="control-label">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <label for="contact-email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control1" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your@example.com">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" class="control-label">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="contact-subject">Subject:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control1" id="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="contact-msg" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Write your message here"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The divs are incorrectly placed, form groups should be inside the column classes.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed that, but it is still not working when I want to display a row and formgroup in a col-md-6! @DavidNguyen

Answer (score 0):

I found the fault! 
When I had this problem I used an old version of bootstrap 3. I used 3.0.0 when I updated to bootstrap 3.0.3 it was working!